# "Undefined symbols for architecture armv7" when importing STATIC LIBRARY that contains OPENCV functions

Tags: xcode, opencv, architecture, static-libraries, armv7

I developed a very simple application, using openCV for iOS. It worked fine until I decided to use that code in another project. The new project shows this `armv7` error and I can't see where the problem is (please, see the last image).

I created a static lib file with my working code, which has the following architecture info:
[image: lib architecture]

Then I compiled it into a `*.a` file and added the `dyOpenCv.a` and the `DyOpenCV.h` files to my main project, which has the following architecture configuration:
[image: Project architecture]

But when I try to use the method within the header file `DyOpenCV.h` I get the following errors:
[image: armv7 error]

Any ideas of what may be wrong?

Comment: They are all linking problems. Make sure you link your project to the libraries that implement those symbols.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There were two issues related to linking libraries:

1. Firstly, although my *subproject* had the `opencv2.framework`
   correctly added and linked to it, I also had to add the framework
   to my main project. This way I got rid of the `cv::*` linking
   problems;
2. The second issue was related to my cross-compiling Objective-C++ configuration. Since I was using `libc++` as my **Standard Library**, I had to add `-lc++` to my **Other Linker Flags**. In case you are using `libstdc++` as your Standard Library, you should add `-lstdc++` instead.

After those changes, it all worked perfectly!
Good luck!

Comment: Hey. I am facing a similar issue. And it's driving me mad. Please, how did you added the framework to your project?
I tried lots of stuff found around the internet, but I always get the linker errors. Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't remind this very well, but I can try sharing the details I still remember, hope it helps: 

I used the concept of `subproject` or `nested project` in Xcode. The subproject had a C dependency and an OpenCV dependency. 

I included those dependencies as libraries to both the subproject and the project.

Comment: Thank you! Will try it and then I will give a feedback wether it worked or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think its because ur project is not linking to the C++ runtime .

Try adding libc++.dylib to ur linked Libraries.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how to do it? Thanks!