# OpenCV undefined error in Xcode

Tags: xcode, opencv, xcode5

I am working on an OpenCV-based project on Xcode 5.02, OS X 10.9.
My OpenCV was installed using homebrew.

I get the following error

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::namedWindow(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)"`

I have added **Header Search Paths** `/usr/local/include nonrecursive` and `/usr/local/include/opencv2 nonrecursive`;

I have added **Library Search Paths** `/usr/local/lib`;

I have added all `.dylib` file under `/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.3/lib` to the project.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, you are trying to run an Objective-C++ project, right? I presume that because cv::nameWindow is a c++ function of OpenCV.

You can have a look on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16240620/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7-when-importing-static-library-that-co), where I had a similar issue and solved it configuring the project properly.

This error means your XCode project is not finding the cv::namedWindow function. Are u sure OpenCV is properly installed in your PC? Can you run the C++ opencv functions from a standard c++ project? If so, the problem is just about your project configuration.